# Where do Minecraft PE can save worlds other than sdcard/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

Minecraft version: 1.1.0.55

I have no worlds yet and when I pressed Play, it asked me: "Did your worlds disappear?" Something like that and asked me to change game default storage location. I chose "Application" and created one world:

[image]

[image]

Then, when I am searching for my world to back it up — because Minecraft PE crashes all the time and is very prone to file corruption — I searched it on games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds, I found nothing:

[image]

I think it's because I chose "Application" as my default storage location. I want to know how to backup​ a world saved in "Application" storage option and can't be found on games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MCPE Android saves to the games Data file, It's inaccessible without Root Access. You could root the Phone and navigate to the file using something like ES file explorer but this does seem like alot of trouble to go to for a Minecraft world (particularly considering the risks of rooting android)

Comment: You can get the file without root. You'll have to jump through a few hoops though. See the post from Tikolu

Answer (score 1):

You should find them somewhere in /data/data/com.mojang.minecraftPE

Note that clearing data will erase your world.

Comment: I do not own the app, so the folder might not be accurate, but the beginning should be right

Comment: Where is that data/data folder? On root? On sdcard? Where. 'coz I only found data on sdcard that contains no com.mojang.minecraftPE and another one on root that also contains nothing

Comment: I'm on Android.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to export worlds saved under "Application Storage" without rooting your device. You will need a Windows computer, a USB Cable and around 10 minutes, but overall it is quite easy. I have created a small program to make this even easier. The program works by using ADB's backup feature to copy all the Minecraft data from the device. The archived data is then extracted using AndroidBackupExtractor and the minecraftWorlds folder is moved from it.

More information and downloads can be found [here](https://tikolu.net/world-exporter/).

*(also, be sure to select External next time to avoid any problems)*

Comment: We need a bit more info than, "this tool".  What is it called?  How does it work?  How should readers use it to resolve the problem?

Comment: If it's your own program, you really should disclose that.  We're super sensitive to spam here.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. I wish I didn't have to install Java though.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the external next time, and the worlds will appear in `games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds` folder.

About the application: I think it isn't possible to redeem an application world.